# Rails 5 - How to create custom scaffold generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

The goal is for command...

`bin/rails generate custom_scaffold Thing`

... to generate the following 6 files:

```
db/migrate/201812031331_create_things.rb
app/models/thing.rb
app/controllers/things_controller.rb
app/serializers/thing_serializer.rb
test/fixtures/things.yml
test/integration/requests/things_request_test.rb
```

... using Rails 5.

My current setup does generate `app/models/thing.rb` but does not populate it with `Thing`.

Expected:

```rb
class Thing < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Currently:

```rb
class <%= class_name %> < ApplicationRecord

end
```

I have read through these [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) but to little avail.

Does anyone have a working example?

---

My setup:

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/custom_scaffold_generator.rb

class CustomScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)

  def create_files
    copy_file 'migration.rb', "db/migrate/#{timestamp}_create_#{plural_name}.rb"
    copy_file 'model.rb', "app/models/#{file_name}.rb"
    copy_file 'controller.rb', "app/controllers/#{plural_name}_controller.rb"
    copy_file 'serializer.rb', "app/serializers/#{file_name}_serializer.rb"
    copy_file 'fixture.yml', "test/fixtures/#{plural_name}.yml"
    copy_file 'request_test.rb', "test/integration/requests/#{plural_name}_request_test.rb"
  end

  private

  def timestamp
    Time.now.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/model.rb

class <%= class_name %> < ApplicationRecord

end
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/controller.rb

module V1
  module Public
    class <%= class_name.pluralize %>Controller < ApplicationController

    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/migration.rb
# Ignore for now
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/serializer.rb
# Ignore for now
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/fixture.yml
# Ignore for now
```

```rb
# lib/generators/custom_scaffold/templates/request_test.rb
# Ignore for now
```

```rb
# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.4.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
gem 'olive_branch'
gem 'fast_jsonapi'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'byebug', '~> 10.0', groups: %i[development test]
gem 'yaml_db'

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'mina', '~> 1.2', require: false
  gem 'mina-puma', require: false
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'annotate', require: false
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the file as a Thor template. Rails uses Thor templates for generating templates with ERB style code inside them.

Replace:
`copy_file 'model.rb', "app/models/#{file_name}.rb"`

With:
`template 'model.rb.tt', "app/models/#{file_name}.rb"`

By adding the `.tt` extension you're telling the generator to handle the file as a Thor template, which will interpret the Ruby code (ERB style) inside the file and then create a file with that same name minus the `.tt` extension. Any file you have without the `.tt` extension the generator will copy wholesale, without executing any of the code inside.

**A useful tip**: Sometimes you want to leave some ERB code inside a Thor template file without it being executed. By default any ERB style tags inside a `.tt` file will be process and in it's place a string will be written to the output file. You can avoid the processing of ERB tags but using a double percent sign in the tag.

For example, lets say you have a file named `foo.erb.tt`, which will create the file `foo.erb` when your generator runs. Let's also say we have a `article_name` variable and it's value is `Breaking News`

If you put `<%= article_name %>` in the file it will write `Breaking News` to the `foo.erb`.

If you put `<%%= article_name %>` (notice the `%%`) it will write `<%= article_name %>`to the `foo.erb`.

I found the following reference handy when learning this stuff.

- [Rails Application Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) article at Rails Guides.
- [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) article at Rails Guides.
- [Thor Actions Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions) these are the commands used in our `template.rb` file.

Thor comes with several actions that help with script and generator tasks. You might be familiar with them since some came from Rails Templates. They are: `say`, `ask`, `yes?`, `no?`, `add_file`, `remove_file`, `copy_file`, `template`, `directory`, `inside`, `run`, `inject_into_file` and a couple more.

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes. Using `template` and adding `.tt` works! Thanks!

Comment: I also  much appreciate the extra tip and documentation links. Just read through.